# What can the "cookie" layer of authentication be called?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, interface, naming

So, I have an MVC framework including an authentication piece. It's been going through all sorts of fun API breaking changes because previously it was a huge static class. I finally had a breakthough as to how abstract it "really" needs to be.

There seem to be three parts to authentication

1. The database interface to store and read usernames, password hashes, etc to/from
2. The "business" logic which handles proper hashing, creating login tokens, and validating them
3. The "exposed" layer which handles cookies or the "user-side persistance" layer which stores a login token. This is usually cookies, could possibly be HTTP Basic Authentication though

Anyway, in the goal of making everything awesome and independently unit testing these 3 layers, I'm making interfaces for these three parts:

1. IUserStore and ISessionStore
2. IAuthMechanism
3. ????

I need help coming with an interface name that makes any sense at all for the user-side persistance layer. Can anyone help me come up with a good name for it? Also, bonus points for names of the implementors (ie, a cookies layer class and an HTTP basic authentication class)

Comment: Have you tried coin toss approach (pick head or tails, toss a coin, if not liking result - toss again till happy)? Pick any name, use it for 10 minutes - refactor if it does not sound right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name should follow directly from the description. In your case you have already described everything, so all that is left is just pick most important pieces. From my point of view the most important thing about third part is that it persists authentication info whether it is cookie or login token or anything else. So why not call it `IAuthPersister` or even `IAuthenticationPersister`? Names for the implementers in this case would be `CookieAuthPersister`, `HttpBasicAuthPersister`, etc., expressing both the layer and the implemented method underneath.